# Why the scaling is changing very slow?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;
    public bool scaleUp = false;
    public Coroutine scaleCoroutine;
    public bool scalingHasFinished = false;
    public DepthOfField depthOfField;

    private void Start()
    {
        transform.localScale = minSize; 
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(depthOfField.depthOfFieldProcessEnded == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ScaleOverTime());
            depthOfField.depthOfFieldProcessEnded = false;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator ScaleOverTime()
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector3 startScaleSize = transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, maxSize, counter / duration);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
        }

        scalingHasFinished = true;
    }
}
```

I want it to scale from the minSize to maxSize over 1 second. But instead it's changing the scale each 1 second by  0.01 until it's getting to the maxSize.

It's making the whole scaling smooth by 1 second.

Comment: `yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);` should be `yield return null;`

Comment: You need to be more specific, "*I want it to scale from the minSize to maxSize over 1 second*" is very loose and ambiguous

Comment: @XenoRo That is not correct. `yield null` is not a statement, it has to be `yield return null`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvwRi.png

Comment: @Draco18s Yep, I was on my celphone and got mixed up. I meant yield return null, yield return any_data, and can't be yield break.

Comment: Explanation to mcrvaz's comment: `yield return` in a coroutine is going to wait before continuing the code; in this case, wait before another run through the while section code. `yield return null` is going to wait only until next frame. `WaitForSeconds` is going to wait for however many frames it takes to cover the specified time. In this case, you just want to skip to the next frame. For that, use `yield return null` (any yield that is not `yield break` will do, but there is no point in yielding data in this case, so `null` is appropriate)